# rabbitmq - getting error operation basic.publish caused a channel exception precondition_failed: fast reply consumer does not exist

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, nestjs, microservices, apple-m1

First time rabbitmq user here. I am using the following command to start rabbitmq using docker.

```
docker run --rm -it -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

I can see that rabbitmq is started and i can open the management cosnole as well. When the individual services in the nestjs application are started, i see queues are getting created on the rabbitmq. But whenever the services try to communicate, following error appears in rabbitmq

```
2022-10-13 08:50:46.763870+00:00 [info] <0.1222.0> connection <0.1222.0> (172.17.0.1:62850 -> 172.17.0.2:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
2022-10-13 08:50:46.773788+00:00 [error] <0.1231.0> Channel error on connection <0.1222.0> (172.17.0.1:62850 -> 172.17.0.2:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'), channel 1:
2022-10-13 08:50:46.773788+00:00 [error] <0.1231.0> operation basic.publish caused a channel exception precondition_failed: fast reply consumer does not exist
2022-10-13 08:50:46.785108+00:00 [warning] <0.1222.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1222.0> (172.17.0.1:62850 -> 172.17.0.2:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
2022-10-13 08:50:46.785108+00:00 [warning] <0.1222.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

I am running this on an apple silicon based mac book.
Is there any idea why this error appearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is the issue.

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/7972

I had to adjust the package versions accordingly to solve this.